# CodeIgniter controller isn't passing information to the model

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm following the details of an example. I'm not sure what the problem is, when I take php out of view within the body, the controller is passing the title into the view. But when I add the simple math problem back into the views body, it seems the controller isn't passing this information into the model. What am I doing wrong here?

Model `math.php`

```
<?php

class Math extends CI_Model {

    public function add($var1, $var2)
    {
        return $var1+ $var2;
    }

    public function subtract($var1, $var2)
    {
        return $var2 - $var1;
    }

}
```

Controller `site.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello World<br>";
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Welcome!';
        $data['var1'] = 2;
        $data['var2'] = 5;

        $this->load->model('math');

        $data['addTotal'] = $this->math->add($data['var1'], $data['var2']);
        $data['subTotal'] = $this->math->subtract($data['var1'], $data['var2']);

        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }

}
```

View `home.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<h3>Add</h3>
<p><?php echo $var1 . " + " . $var2 " = " $addTotal; ?></p>

<h3>Subtract</h3>
<p><?php echo $var2 . " - " . $var1 " = " $subTotal; ?></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the view loading or script gives a blank page ?

Comment: there seems to be no problem in your code , have you set the error reporting on so that you could get some help. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the output...

Hello World

Add

2 + 5 = 7

Subtract

5 - 2 = 3

you forgot to **concat** the "="

```
<h3>Add</h3>
<p><?php echo $var1 . " + " . $var2 " = " $addTotal; ?></p>

<h3>Subtract</h3>
<p><?php echo $var2 . " - " . $var1 " = " $subTotal; ?></p>
```

**should be...**

```
<h3>Add</h3>
<p><?php echo $var1 . " + " . $var2 . " = " . $addTotal; ?></p>

<h3>Subtract</h3>
<p><?php echo $var2 . " - " . $var1.  " = " . $subTotal; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It might help.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class Site extends CI_Controller {

            public function __construct()
            {
              parent::__construct();       
              $this->load->model('math');

            }
            public function index()
            {
                echo "Hello World<br>";
                $this->home();
            }

            public function home()
            {
                $data['title'] = 'Welcome!';
                $data['var1'] = 2;
                $data['var2'] = 5;
                $data['addTotal'] = $this->math->add($data['var1'], $data['var2']);
                $data['subTotal'] = $this->math->subtract($data['var1'], $data['var2']);

                $this->load->view('home', $data);
            }

        }
```

EDIT :

To turn on error reporting go to the main index.php file in ci , the one which is in the same directory as your application folder and make sure environment is set to development

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Comment: As before, only the echo within index is displaying. Then the rest is just a blank screen. I did receive fatal warnings when I messed with the code, but other than that, do I need to have more error reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it will work's fine.

```
    <div id="container">
       <h3>Add</h3>
       <p><?php echo $var1+$var2; ?></p>
       <h3>Subtract</h3>
       <p><?php echo $var2-$var1; ?></p>
    </div>
```